# Olympics connect?

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, sports

Since the CS50x Puzzle Day 2018 has ended here in the USA, I think I can now ask this question. The following table has been given and we need to find a single word related to it. The logic could be anything, no restrictions. Try to think outside the box as much as possible.

[image: Puzzle 7 from CS50x 2018]

CSV version:

```
Amsterdam,Athletics: Men's 5000 meters,Gold
Antwerp,Boxing: Men's lightweight,Bronze
Athens,Fencing: Women's individual foil,Silver
Grenoble,Cross-country Skiing: Men's 15km,Silver
Montreal,Boxing: Men's light heavyweight,Silver
Nagano,Alpine Skiing: Men's giant slalom,Bronze
Oslo,Speed Skating: Men's 500 meters,Gold
Rio de Janeiro,Athletics: Women's 800 meters,Bronze
Seoul,Canoeing: Men's K1 500 meters kayak singles,Gold,
Tokyo,Fencing: Women's individual foil,Bronze
Vancouver,Cross-country Skiing: Women's sprint,Silver
```

I found out all the winners and their respective countries and tried fiddling with them, but no luck. I also made a tally of the medals and tried something with binary numbers as well. I also tried some other normal arithmetic calculations, no luck there either. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

[The link to the puzzle packet](http://cs50.ly/puzzles18). This is problem number 7 in this packet.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) Could you share the link to the original source of the puzzle, please.

Comment: @ABcDexter edited!

Answer (score 8):

<sup>Okay, this is a puzzle I've looked at multiple times over the past couple of years and never managed to find my way through to a solution. So - full disclosure - I've done some research online to see if a solution had ever been posted anywhere else. *And I found one.* Hidden away, within [a CS50 blog post](https://cs50.medium.com/this-was-cs50x-puzzle-day-2018-22d95a48615), in an embedded and **unlisted** [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4No23j0hpQ&list=PLhQjrBD2T381CiQGzSGT9IAY5MQYawuGu). But as far as I can tell there is *no write-up* anywhere easily found online - so here we go: the solution to this puzzle; research and write-up mine, but the solution as provided by the puzzle's creators...</sup>

---

The first step to solving this puzzle is a big data collection exercise. A table similar to the one compiled by @DqwertyC is a good place to start:

| Year | Host City | Event | Medal | Athlete | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1928 | Amsterdam | Athletics: Men's 5000 meters | Gold | Ville Ritola | Finland |
| 1920 | Antwerp | Boxing: Men's lightweight | Bronze | Clarence Newton | Canada |
| 2004 | Athens | Fencing: Women's individual foil | Silver | Giovanna Trillini | Italy |
| 1968 | Grenoble | Cross-country Skiing: Men's 15km | Silver | Eero Mäntyranta | Finland |
| 1976 | Montreal | Boxing: Men's light heavyweight | Silver | Sixto Soria | Cuba |
| 1998 | Nagano | Alpine Skiing: Men's giant slalom | Bronze | Michael von Grünigen | Switzerland |
| 1952 | Oslo | Speed Skating: Men's 500 meters | Gold | Ken Henry | USA |
| 2016 | Rio de Janeiro | Athletics: Women's 800 meters | Bronze | Margaret Wambui | Kenya |
| 1988 | Seoul | Canoeing: Men's K1 500 meters kayak singles | Gold | Zsolt Gyulai | Hungary |
| 1964 | Tokyo | Fencing: Women's individual foil | Bronze | Antonella Ragno | Italy |
| 2010 | Vancouver | Cross-country Skiing: Women's sprint | Silver | Justyna Kowalczyk | Poland |

Note here in row 3 that we have selected the 2004 Athens Olympics rather than the one in 1896, since this is the only one of the two to feature the fencing event in question. Also, we can ignore the recent '2020' Tokyo games (which played out late in 2021, of course), since these post-date the original question.

Now, in this type of puzzle hunt question we generally need to look for a way to extract a one-word (occasionally, one-phrase) answer from the data available, and usually this will involve *systematically* extracting one, two or more letters from each entry in the data table. There are very few clues provided in this puzzle, making it particularly difficult to find the solution without a great deal of trial and error. And, in fact, our task on PSE was made *even* harder as a result of the one clue that *was* provided to the CS50x Puzzle Day 2018 participants *being omitted from the puzzle as presented here!*

Here's a link to the original [puzzle packet PDF file](https://cdn.cs50.net/2018/x/events/puzzles/2018_puzzle_packet.pdf), with the relevant page reproduced below:

[image: Puzzle in full as per original puzzle packet]

We see here that the title of the original puzzle was **Medal Table** - and this is intended by the puzzle setters to indicate not just the table presented to us but a hint as to how to solve it...

> Consider the data table we've collected. Among the data available to us we have the *countries* represented by the winning athletes. We need to *look up the final **medal table** for each Olympic Games listed here and find out **how many of the specified medal that country won***.
>
>  For example, at the [1928 Amsterdam Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1928_Summer_Olympics_medal_table), Finland finished third with 8 gold medals; while at the [1920 Antwerp Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_Summer_Olympics_medal_table), Canada placed twelfth with 3 bronze medals.

Let's seek this information out for the other entries in the table and add this in:

| Year | Host City | Event | Medal | Athlete | Country |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1928 | Amsterdam | Athletics: Men's 5000 meters | Gold | Ville Ritola | Finland | 8 |
| 1920 | Antwerp | Boxing: Men's lightweight | Bronze | Clarence Newton | Canada | 3 |
| 2004 | Athens | Fencing: Women's individual foil | Silver | Giovanna Trillini | Italy | 11 |
| 1968 | Grenoble | Cross-country Skiing: Men's 15km | Silver | Eero Mäntyranta | Finland | 2 |
| 1976 | Montreal | Boxing: Men's light heavyweight | Silver | Sixto Soria | Cuba | 4 |
| 1998 | Nagano | Alpine Skiing: Men's giant slalom | Bronze | Michael von Grünigen | Switzerland | 3 |
| 1952 | Oslo | Speed Skating: Men's 500 meters | Gold | Ken Henry | USA | 4 |
| 2016 | Rio de Janeiro | Athletics: Women's 800 meters | Bronze | Margaret Wambui | Kenya | 1 |
| 1988 | Seoul | Canoeing: Men's K1 500 meters kayak singles | Gold | Zsolt Gyulai | Hungary | 11 |
| 1964 | Tokyo | Fencing: Women's individual foil | Bronze | Antonella Ragno | Italy | 7 |
| 2010 | Vancouver | Cross-country Skiing: Women's sprint | Silver | Justyna Kowalczyk | Poland | 3 |

Now, we use these numbers to...

> ...**index into the names** of the medal winners. i.e. take the 8th letter of Ville Ritola's name (T), then the 3rd letter of 'Clarence Newton' (A), and proceed similarly down the table.

| Year | Host City | Event | Medal | Athlete | Country |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1928 | Amsterdam | Athletics: Men's 5000 meters | Gold | Ville Ri**t**ola | Finland | 8 | T |
| 1920 | Antwerp | Boxing: Men's lightweight | Bronze | Cl**a**rence Newton | Canada | 3 | A |
| 2004 | Athens | Fencing: Women's individual foil | Silver | Giovanna Tr**i**llini | Italy | 11 | I |
| 1968 | Grenoble | Cross-country Skiing: Men's 15km | Silver | E**e**ro Mäntyranta | Finland | 2 | E |
| 1976 | Montreal | Boxing: Men's light heavyweight | Silver | Six**t**o Soria | Cuba | 4 | T |
| 1998 | Nagano | Alpine Skiing: Men's giant slalom | Bronze | Mi**c**hael von Grünigen | Switzerland | 3 | C |
| 1952 | Oslo | Speed Skating: Men's 500 meters | Gold | Ken **H**enry | USA | 4 | H |
| 2016 | Rio de Janeiro | Athletics: Women's 800 meters | Bronze | **M**argaret Wambui | Kenya | 1 | M |
| 1988 | Seoul | Canoeing: Men's K1 500 meters kayak singles | Gold | Zsolt Gyula**i** | Hungary | 11 | I |
| 1964 | Tokyo | Fencing: Women's individual foil | Bronze | Antone**l**la Ragno | Italy | 7 | L |
| 2010 | Vancouver | Cross-country Skiing: Women's sprint | Silver | Ju**s**tyna Kowalczyk | Poland | 3 | S |

And now one step remains...

> Note that the list was originally sorted alphabetically by host city. If instead we sort the table by **the year of the Games**, we reorder the extracted letters as follows:
>
>  1920 **A**
>  1928 **T**
>  1952 **H**
>  1964 **L**
>  1968 **E**
>  1976 **T**
>  1988 **I**
>  1998 **C**
>  2004 **I**
>  2010 **S**
>  2016 **M**

i.e. The hidden (and thematic) one-word answer to this puzzle is:

> **ATHLETICISM**!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the table as CSV. I've also added the individual and the country for the given medal, and the year that that Olympics took place. Hopefully this will help someone with better pattern recognition skills:

```
Host City,Year,Event,Medal,Individual,Country
Amsterdam,1928,Athletics: Men's 5000m,Gold,Ville Ritola,Finland
Antwerp,1920,Boxing: Man's lightweight,Bronze,Clarence Newton,Canada
Athens,2004,Fencing: Women's Individual Foil,Silver,Giovanna Trillini,Italy
Grenoble,1968,Cross-Country Skiing: Men's 15km,Silver,Eero Mantyranta,Finland
Montreal,1976,Boxing: Men's Light Heavyweight,Silver,Sixto Soria,Cuba
Nagano,1998,Alpine Skiing: Men's Giant Slalom,Bronze,Michael von Grünigen,Switzerland
Oslo,1952,Speed Skating: Men's 500 meters,Gold,Ken Henry,USA
Rio de Janeiro,2016,Athletics: Women's 800 meters,Bronze,MARGARET WAMBUI,Kenya
Seoul,1988,Canoeing: Man's K I 500 meters kayak singles,Gold,Zsolt Gyulay,Hungary
Tokyo,1964,Fencing: Women's Individual Foil,Bronze,Antonella Ragno,Italy
Vancouver,2010,Cross-Country Skiing: Women's Spring,Silver,Justyna Kowalczyk,Poland
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a work in progress / a reference to help other solve this question too.

---

Reproducing the data in the image:

1. Amsterdam -- Athletics: Men's 5000 meters -- GOLD
2. Antwerp -- Boxing: Men's lightweight -- BRONZE
3. Athens -- Fencing: Women's individual foil -- SILVER
4. Grenoble -- Cross-country Skiing: Men's 15km -- SILVER
5. Montreal -- Boxing: Men's light heavyweight -- SILVER
6. Nagano -- Alpine Skiing: Men's giant slalom -- BRONZE
7. Oslo -- Speed Skating: Men's 500 meters -- GOLD
8. Rio de Janeiro -- Athletics: Women's 800 meters -- BRONZE
9. Seoul -- Canoeing: Men's K1 500 meters kayak singles -- GOLD
10. Tokyo -- Fencing: Women's individual foil -- BRONZE
11. Vancouver -- Cross-country Skiing: Women's sprint -- SILVER

...and now retrieving links for each event:

1. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1928/ATH/mens-5000-metres.html
2. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1920/BOX/mens-lightweight.html
3. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/2004/FEN/womens-foil-individual.html
4. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/winter/1968/CCS/mens-15-kilometres.html
5. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1976/BOX/mens-light-heavyweight.html
6. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/winter/1998/ASK/mens-giant-slalom.html
7. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/winter/1952/SSK/mens-500-metres.html
8. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/2016/ATH/womens-800-metres.html
9. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1988/CAN/mens-kayak-singles-500-metres.html
10. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1964/FEN/womens-foil-individual.html
11. https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/winter/2010/CCS/womens-sprint.html

...and now correlating with medals to get athlete data (apologies for the bad unicode -- I blame sports-reference for that):

1. `{'name': 'Ville Ritola', 'age': 32, 'country': 'Finland'}`
2. `{'name': 'Chris Newton', 'age': 21, 'country': 'Canada'}`
3. `{'name': 'Giovanna Trillini', 'age': 34, 'country': 'Italy'}`
4. `{'name': 'Eero MÃ¤ntyranta', 'age': 30, 'country': 'Finland'}`
5. `{'name': 'Sixto Soria', 'age': 22, 'country': 'Cuba'}`
6. `{'name': 'Michael von GrÃ¼nigen', 'age': 28, 'country': 'Switzerland'}`
7. `{'name': 'Ken Henry', 'age': 23, 'country': 'United States'}`
8. `{'name': 'Margaret Wambui', 'age': 20, 'country': 'Kenya'}`
9. `{'name': 'Zsolt Gyulay', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Hungary'}`
10. `{'name': 'Antonella Ragno-Lonzi', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Italy'}`
11. `{'name': 'Justyna Kowalczyk', 'age': 27, 'country': 'Poland'}`